# SQLAlchemy not creating table in database

Tags: python, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am creating a website using a flask with a signup form that saves the signup info in a database. however, it is not creating any tables in the database.
my **init**.py file looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path



#intitialising databas: works correctly
db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = 'database.db'



def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'shhh dont tell'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)

    #importing our blue prints
    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth


    app.register_blueprint(views,urlprefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth,urlprefix='/')

    from .models import User

    create_database(app)



    return app

#database creates successfully 
def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('website/source' + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print('Created Database')
```

and my models.py looks like:

```
from enum import unique
from sqlalchemy import true
from website.source import db
from flask_login import UserMixin



#schema of table according to mega tut and sqlalchemy 
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstName = db.Column(db.String(150))
    lastName = db.Column(db.String(150))
    userName = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
```

I am not sure why this is happing. when I run the app on the flask and do my sign up form and click the submit button I get the error

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table user has no column named userName

I have looked at multiple youtube tutorials and I seem to be doing everything correctly. any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: `if not path.exists('website/source' + DB_NAME)` - maybe you created an empty db first and you're reusing that?

Comment: Have you changed or added the `userName` attribute on the model since the database was originally created?  The error message implies that the table is found, but not the column.

Comment: @Peter I am just checking that I do not overwrite the database. i have opened the data base however and there are no tabled inside of it

Comment: @snakecharmerb that worked thanks! I understand the problem now. How can I drop a table in the flask?

Comment: I'm not sure there's an easy way in flask itself; you can run `db.drop_all()` which will drop _all_ the tables, or just delete the current SQLite file.If your machine has the SQLite CLI executable installed (`sqlite3` (linux), `sqlite3.exe` (windows)) you can use that to drop the table.